# Symfony LiipImagine Path filter

Tags: symfony, liipimaginebundle

I've got a problem with my path.

If I put this

```
{% set img = 'upload/img/'~cars.image~'' %}
<img src="{{img|imagine_filter('recherche') }}" alt="{{ cars.name}}{{ cars.model}}" />
```

I've got an 404 error "app_dev.php/media/cache/resolve/recherche/upload/img/upload/img/79.jpeg"

So I try to remove 'upload/img/' but I have this error :

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Parameter "path" for route "liip_imagine_filter" must match ".+" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL.") in VAPlatformBundle:Default:research.html.twig at line 50.
```

I am a little confused.

Thx for your help!

Comment: By any chance, didn't you forget to change routing.yml when installing LiipImagineBundle (adding LiipImagineBundle routes) as described here http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/LiipImagineBundle/installation.html#step-3-register-the-bundle-s-routes ?

Comment: Could you display the result of `{{ dump(cars.image) }}`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line

> {% set img = 'upload/img/'~cars.image~'' %}

by

> {% set img = 'upload/img/'~cars.image %}